# windows 11 computer frozen

Tags: freeze, windows-11

Just installed Win 11 from official MS download. Was asking the Dell community about reinstalling my 3rd monitor the PC froze up. Rebooted with all plugged in and PC again froze. Everything worked with Win 10. Compatibility check was run before 11 install. Came back as "Compatible." PC less than 1 yr old. Dell XPS 9700. Why is it continuously freezing? Not knowledgeable except for the apps I use. Thanks

Comment: Uninstall `Dell Support Assist`.

Comment: Also roll back to Windows 10 right away until you can sort this out. Do not wait to roll back.

Comment: Downloading https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/intel-driver-support-assistant.html might also help.

Comment: Listen to @John .. since Microsoft fired all of the real testers, you are essentially running a Windows 11 beta.  Wait for all of the other stooges to work out the kinks before jumping on any release from Microsoft that is less than a year old.

Answer (score 0):

> Just installed Win 11 from official MS download. Was asking the Dell
> community about reinstalling my 3rd monitor the PC froze up. Rebooted
> with all plugged in and PC again froze. Everything worked with Win 10.

There is a limit of 10 days on rolling back to Windows 10.

I would not waste any time in rolling back since (a) your system worked fine with Windows 10 and (b) Microsoft appears to be enforcing the limit of 10 days.

Better that your computer work than not work.

You can always go back to Windows 11 when you sort out the issues with your computer.

[Roll back to Windows 10](https://www.zdnet.com/article/you-can-easily-roll-back-windows-11-to-windows-10-until-this-bonkers-policy-kicks-in/?ftag=TRE-03-10aaa6b&bhid=%7B%24external_id%7D&mid=%7B%24MESSAGE_ID%7D&cid=%7B%24contact_id%7D&eh=%7B%24CF_emailHash%7D)

> For no reason other than that it can, Microsoft will allow you to
> revert to Windows 10 within 10 days of updating to Windows 11. Should
> you decide on Day 11 or Day 15 that you'd like that old comfortable OS
> back, you're out of luck.
>
> From the Start menu, choose System, then Recovery, then Go Back.
> Answer a simple question about why you're reverting your Windows
> installation, and wait. Shortly later, your machine will restart. When
> it does, it will once again be running Windows 10.